# vim netrw-qb conflicts with q recording

Tags: vim, netrw

Under *netrw*, pressing `qb`(query bookmark) will list bookmarks etc. But this key is preempted by `q` recording. It becomes recording to register b.

What's your suggestion to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Just place the following to your `.vimrc` file.

```
autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer>q <Nop>
```

---

I have not found any command in the `help netrw` but you can always type `tabe . | :nnoremap qb` and get as the output:

```
n  qb          *@:<C-U>call <SNR>75_NetrwBookHistHandler(2,b:netrw_curdir)<CR>
```

You will be wrong if you just `nnoremap` this to a `qb` since the script id (75) may be changed in the future. So the following is wrong, do not do this:

```
autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer><silent>qb :call <SNR>75_NetrwBookHistHandler(2,b:netrw_curdir)<CR>
```

As `netrw` help file says there is an option `g:Netrw_UserMaps` which allow us to bind user functions `help netrw-usermaps`.

**Solution #1**

```
function! NetrwBookHistHandler(isLocal)                                                                                                                                       
    return "call <SID>NetrwBookHistHandler(2, b:netrw_curdir)"
endfunction

let g:Netrw_UserMaps = [["qb", "NetrwBookHistHandler"]]
```

Function returned string, if not empty, will be executed in the `netrw` script context which makes possible to access actual `<SID>`.

**Update**

<del>Solution #2</del>

If you type `:call netrw#<C-D>` you will see there is a function called `netrw#Call`. So the solution becomes a little bit easier:

```
autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer><silent>qb :call netrw#Call("NetrwBookHistHandler", 2, b:netrw_curdir)
```

**Update 2**

Unfortunately, there is a bug in `netrw` plugin code.

```
" /usr/share/nvim/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim

fun! netrw#Call(funcname,...)                                                                                                                                                 
"  call Dfunc("netrw#Call(funcname<".a:funcname.">,".string(a:000).")")
  if a:0 > 0
   exe "call s:".a:funcname."(".string(a:000).")"
  else
   exe "call s:".a:funcname."()"
  endif
"  call Dret("netrw#Call")
endfun
```

When we call `netrw#Call("NetrwBookHistHandler", 2, b:netrw_curdir)` the function itself call `NetrwBookHistHandler([2, b:netrw_curdir])` while `NetrwBookHistHandler` expects 2 parameters. Use the second and the easiest solution.

**Solution #2**

```
autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer>q <Nop>
```

Comment: You can try `:h netrw-qb`.

Comment: Is that possible to disable `q` recording in `netrw`? I don't think we'll use key recording in `netrw`.

Comment: You can prevent `q` from recording setting it to do nothing: `autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer>q <Nop>`. But what is wrong with the last command I posted above?

Comment: Do you mean all I need to add is `autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer><silent>qb :call netrw#Call("NetrwBookHistHandler(2, b:netrw_curdir)")`?
Nothing happens if I press `qb` under _netrw_.
I input command directly `:call netrw#Call("NetrwBookHistHandler(2, b:netrw_curdir)")`, got error : Unknown function: s:NetrwBookHisHandler(2, b:netrw_curdir)

Comment: What do you get as an output typing `tabe . | :nnoremap qb`? Have you tried to map `q` no `<Nop>` or set `g:Netrw_UserMaps` option as described in the answer?

Comment: `autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer>q <Nop>` works. `qb` does show the list.

Comment: `tabe . | :nnoremap qb` does show `n  qb          *@:<C-U>call <SNR>75_NetrwBookHistHandler(2,b:netrw_curdir)<CR>`. Strange part is two means (`autocmd` or `g:Netrw_UserMaps`) all lead to "Unknown function"

Comment: I have no problems with `g:Netrw_UserMaps` but the last command seems to be incorrect. It worked for me too (window is shown) but there is "trailing character` error which is not good. However, the function exists. I do not know why you get this error. You may `set verbose=15` and `set verbosefile=~/.vim/logs` to debug. Also see `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim` to better understand what `netrw` is actually doing. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I think you should emphasize in the answer that we should remap `qb` to the other key combination. (`let g:Netrw_UserMaps = [["qb", "NetrwBookHistHandler"]]`) or it still conflict with `q` recording. Your answer and suggestion is thoroughly, thanks.